# ordered list two column flow

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-multicolumn-layout

I want a preferably CSS-only technique for getting an `ol` to flow into two columns if it is longer than the height of the container. The number of items in the list may vary and the height of the container may change.

When I try setting the li to `width:50%` and `float:left` it goes in two columns but 2 goes beside 1 instead of below it.

what I want to achieve is this:

1. abcdef  4. abcdef
2. abcdef  5. abcdef
3. abcdef

Comment: Have you tried this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194803/automatic-two-columns-with-css-or-javascript?rq=1) `Automatic two columns with CSS or JavaScript`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will work for modern browsers (i.e not IE) using the `column-count` and `column-gap` rules:

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Mvj/1/)

```
ol#two-columns {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

The cross-browser option would be:

1. define two DIVs inside the OL and float them to the left
2. pre-calculate the total number of LI's
3. if the total exceeds the capacity of one DIV, put the rest in the second DIV