# Prevent premature wrapping in 2-column HTML report using CSS

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, weasyprint

I'm building a two-column "report" in HTML and CSS (I'm new to both) and printing it to a PDF via Weasyprint in Python. My problem is that content in the first column is wrapping into the second column prematurely, ultimately resulting in a broken table that should remain in one column:

[image]

The HTML file calls the CSS file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="report.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Report</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Report example">
    </head>
    ...
```

at some point, I create a page style in CSS called "satgeom":

```
@page {
  @top-left {
    background: #FF874A;
    content: counter(page);
    height: 1cm;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1cm;
  }
  @top-center {
    background: #FF874A;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: .05cm;
    opacity: .5;
    width: 100%;
  }
  @top-right {
    content: string(heading);
    font-size: 9pt;
    height: 1cm;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@page :blank {
  @top-left { background: none; content: '' }
  @top-center { content: none }
  @top-right { content: none }
}
@page no-chapter {
  @top-left { background: none; content: none }
  @top-center { content: none }
  @top-right { content: none }
}
@page :first {
  background: url(report_cover.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
@page chapter {
  background: #FF874A;
  margin: 0;
  @top-left { content: none }
  @top-center { content: none }
  @top-right { content: none }
}

html {
  color: #393939;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
  color: #FF874A;
  font-size: 38pt;
  margin: 5cm 2cm 0 2cm;
  page: no-chapter;
  width: 100%;
}
h2, h3, h4 {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
  break-before: always;
  font-size: 28pt;
  string-set: heading content();
}
h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 13pt;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

#satgeom section {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 1cm;
}
#satgeom section p {
  text-align: justify;
}

/* Table */
.tg {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-zv4m{border-color:#fcbb9a;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-ofj5{border-color:#fcbb9a;text-align:right;vertical-align:top}
```

and call this style in the HTML. The contents of this page contain a lengthy table and text. My problem is that the table is wrapping prematurely, and I cannot figure out why. Ideally, I would like to wrap the text into the second column *after* the first column fills up. A snippet of my HTML for the "satgeom" page is as follows:

```
<article id="satgeom">
  <h2 id="satgeom-title">Satellite geometry</h2>

  <h3>Satellite geometry, depiction, and description</h3>

  <section>
    <img src="./satellite.png" alt="">
    <p>
      <table class="tg" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 300px">
        <colgroup>
          <col style="width: 150px">
          <col style="width: 150px">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Name</th>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">Uydu</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Cost [$]</th>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">600,000,000</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Manufacturer</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">TAI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Duration [years]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Orbit altitude [km]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">35,785</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Max. velocity [km/s]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">11,051</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Dy mass [kg]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">1,577</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">NORAD ID</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5"> - </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Uplink [GHz]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">7.3 - 18.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Downlink [GHz]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">11.70 - 12.75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Reference frame</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">Geocentric</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Regime</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">Geostationary</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </p>
    <p>
      Launched in 2024, the Uydu satellite was manufactured by the Turkish
      Aerospace Industries for roughly $600,000,000. The satellite's mission
      is 
    </p>
    <p>
      Construction-wise, the Uydu satellite comprises a main body and two 
      solar panel arrays extending laterally to its side. For power consumption, 
      the solar panels can be rotated to face the sun.
    </p>
  </section>
</article>
```

I've tried adding a `div{}` to my CSS file and messed with the [nowrap property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/two-inline-block-width-50-elements-wrap-to-second-line), [modifying the CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194803/how-to-make-text-over-flow-into-two-columns-automatically), and have also done a number of Google / SO searches, but haven't found a solution. Honestly, I'm not sure I'm looking for the right phrases.

---

Edit:
Stefan's answer below resulted in the "baseball card" solution I was looking for:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [avoid page break inside row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

Comment: No, since I'm not trying to address a page break *inside a row*, but rather the table itself being distributed across different columns.

Comment: If you add `page-break-inside: avoid` to a whole table it will stop breaking it into two separate tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a div with two divs inside it for each column.

Something like this:

```html
<article id="satgeom">
  <h2 id="satgeom-title">Satellite geometry</h2>

  <h3>Satellite geometry, depiction, and description</h3>

  <div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 50%; padding-right: 2em;">
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="./satellite.png" alt="">
      <table class="tg" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
        <colgroup>
          <col style="width: 150px">
          <col style="width: 150px">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Name</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">Uydu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Cost [$]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">600,000,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Manufacturer</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">TAI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Duration [years]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Orbit altitude [km]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">35,785</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Max. velocity [km/s]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">11,051</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Dy mass [kg]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">1,577</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">NORAD ID</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5"> - </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Uplink [GHz]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">7.3 - 18.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Downlink [GHz]</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">11.70 - 12.75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Reference frame</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">Geocentric</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-zv4m">Regime</td>
          <td class="tg-ofj5">Geostationary</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%;">
        <p>
          Launched in 2024, the Uydu satellite was manufactured by the Turkish
          Aerospace Industries for roughly $600,000,000. The satellite's mission
          is
        </p>
        <p>
          Construction-wise, the Uydu satellite comprises a main body and two
          solar panel arrays extending laterally to its side. For power consumption,
          the solar panels can be rotated to face the sun.
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This begins to address the issue -- now the table is all in one column. However, now text from the second column is being printed on top of the image in the top of the first column. If I remember the second `div`, things are better, but the text under the table is spread across both columns instead of being contained into one, then flowing into the second column.

Comment: I have installed weasyprint and now I see what you mean. I've edited my comment to make each div 50% of the width of the page and remove the hardcoded table width.

Comment: That worked beautifully, and it's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 problem in your code, first you have declared your columns for the section within the `#satgeom section` selector, that will make the `<section>` element distributed across two columns, including the table, lets make the  table stays in one column.

```
#satgeom section table {
    column-span: all;
}
```

Also the table is wrapped table with a `<p>` tag, lets replace this:

```
<p>
  <table class="tg" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 300px">
  ...
  </table>
</p>
```

with

```
<table class="tg" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 300px">
...
</table>
```

Comment: applying these solutions does not solve the issue, the table is still broken in the same manner as the opening image.